# Relationship between two traingles that have same adjacent side

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles

If we have two triangles $akz$ and $bkc$ in which they have same side $k$.

If $t_1$ and $t_2$ are two angles $\in \thinspace]0\thinspace , \thinspace 90[$ in which the above-mentioned $k$ is the *adjacent* as shown in the following image:

[two triangles illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EXRD.png)

Can we prove that:

if $b > a > k$ $\Rightarrow$ $c > z$ is always true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  $X = (0, 0)$, $Y = (4, 0)$ and $Z = (4, 2)$, and 
$W = (5, 1)$. Here $k = [X, Y]$, $a = [X, Z]$, $ z =  [Y, Z]$ and
$ b = [X, W]$ and $ c = [Y, W]$. Note, $|k| = 4$, $|a| = \sqrt{20}$ $|z| = 2$, 
$|b| = \sqrt{26}$, and $|c| = \sqrt{2}$.

Geometrywise, $b$ is outside the circle of radius $|a|$ and centre  $X$ (not too far) and much nearer the line $k$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, before accepting it I just wanna make sure: Is that also applicable in $3D$?

Comment: [Here](https://www.matheretter.de/calc/geodrafter/?draw=point(0%7C0%20%22X%22)+point(4%7C0%20%22Y%22)+point(4%7C2%20%22Z%22)+point(5%7C1%20%22W%22)++vector(0%7C0%204%7C0)+vector(0%7C0%204%7C2)+vector(4%7C0%204%7C2)+vector(0%7C0%205%7C1)+vector(4%7C0%205%7C1)+&scale=10) is a link of your example, you can take a screenshot and add it to your answer